# Inverse ZCA whitening

Tags: python, transform

I have the following code to transform to ZCA, but I am unfamiliar with how to inverse the transform

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNetCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import numpy as np

def read_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thistleknot/Python-Stock/master/data/raw/states.csv").set_index('States')
    return(df)

def whiten(X):
    #just an np array
    X = X.reshape((-1, np.prod(X.shape[1:])))
    
    X_centered = X - np.mean(X, axis=0)
    
    Sigma = np.dot(X_centered.T, X_centered) / X_centered.shape[0]
    
    W = None
    U, Lambda, _ = np.linalg.svd(Sigma)
    W = np.dot(U, np.dot(np.diag(1.0 / np.sqrt(Lambda + 1e-5)), U.T))
    transformed = np.dot(X_centered, W.T)
    
    return transformed

pd.DataFrame(whiten(np.array(read_data())))
```

Answer (score 1):

found the inverse here
https://github.com/devyhia/cifar-10/blob/master/zca.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# ------------------------------------
# file: zca.py
# date: Thu May 21 15:47 2015
# author:
# Maarten Versteegh
# github.com/mwv
# maartenversteegh AT gmail DOT com
#
# Licensed under GPLv3
# ------------------------------------
"""zca: ZCA whitening with a sklearn-like interface

"""

from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils import check_array, as_float_array

class ZCA(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, regularization=1e-6, copy=False):
        self.regularization = regularization
        self.copy = copy

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        """Compute the mean, whitening and dewhitening matrices.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like with shape [n_samples, n_features]
            The data used to compute the mean, whitening and dewhitening
            matrices.
        """
        X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=None, copy=self.copy,
                        ensure_2d=True)
        X = as_float_array(X, copy=self.copy)
        self.mean_ = X.mean(axis=0)
        X_ = X - self.mean_
        cov = np.dot(X_.T, X_) / (X_.shape[0]-1)
        U, S, _ = linalg.svd(cov)
        s = np.sqrt(S.clip(self.regularization))
        s_inv = np.diag(1./s)
        s = np.diag(s)
        self.whiten_ = np.dot(np.dot(U, s_inv), U.T)
        self.dewhiten_ = np.dot(np.dot(U, s), U.T)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, copy=None):
        """Perform ZCA whitening

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like with shape [n_samples, n_features]
            The data to whiten along the features axis.
        """
        check_is_fitted(self, 'mean_')
        X = as_float_array(X, copy=self.copy)
        return np.dot(X - self.mean_, self.whiten_.T)

    def inverse_transform(self, X, copy=None):
        """Undo the ZCA transform and rotate back to the original
        representation

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like with shape [n_samples, n_features]
            The data to rotate back.
        """
        check_is_fitted(self, 'mean_')
        X = as_float_array(X, copy=self.copy)
        return np.dot(X, self.dewhiten_) + self.mean_
```